# Laravel file upload error Content-Length

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Error

```
Warning: POST Content-Length of 31492035 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0
```

App.php

```
'allowedFileTypes' => 'jpg,jpeg,bmp,png,pdf,mp4',
'maxFileSize' => 10000000000*2,
```

Controller Create

```
$rules = ['attachments.*' => 'required|mimes:'.$allowedFileTypes.'|max:'.$maxFileSize];
Storage::put($destinationPath.$fileName.'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension(),file_get_contents($file->getRealPath()));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

8388608 bytes is 8M, the default limit in PHP. Update your `post_max_size` in php.ini to a larger value.

`upload_max_filesize` sets the max file size that a user can upload while post_max_size sets the maximum amount of data that can be sent via a POST in a form.

So you can make `upload_max_filesize` larger.

Comment: I changed `post_max_size = 8M` to `post_max_size = 50M` and I refreshed WampServer. Same Error any suggestion?